# Drop Header in Akka HTTP response

Tags: akka-http

I am using Akka HTTP 10.0.15. Each response contains the header `Server: akka-http/10.0.15`. Is there any way to drop this header? I couldn't find anything in the list of directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `application.conf`, set `akka.http.server.server-header` to the empty string:

```
akka.http.server.server-header = ""
```

From the [reference configuration](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.1.8/configuration.html):

```
akka.http {

  server {
    # The default value of the `Server` header to produce if no
    # explicit `Server`-header was included in a response.
    # If this value is the empty string and no header was included in
    # the request, no `Server` header will be rendered at all.
    server-header = akka-http/${akka.http.version}

    ...
  }

  ...
}
```